# Macro in Excel to remove rows containing all 0's

Tags: string, excel, rows, vba

Okay so here is the table set up I'm working with:

[image]

I need a macro to remove the rows containing four 0's, the only way I can think of at the moment requires the cells to be empty, i.e. ""

Does 0 actually count as a string or digit or is it equivalent to "" ?

I think the problem might be related to the fact that some of my 0's are text strings and others are numbers, I just didn't think this would matter.

Comment: So you would want to remove rows 2.4.5.9.10?

Comment: I would just write a loop that goes through each row, and deletes it if the sum of the cells is = 0

Answer (score 0):

Here, I got one for you. Try with this.

```
Public Sub removeRow()

    Dim row As Integer

    'Set the start row.
    row = 1

    'Loop all row from sheet until colum "A" cell is blank
    Do While Sheets("sheetname").Range("A" & row) <> ""

        'If all cell are 0.
        If Sheets("sheetname").Range("A" & row) = 0 And Sheets("sheetname").Range("B" & row) = 0 And Sheets("sheetname").Range("C" & row) = 0 And Sheets("sheetname").Range("D" & row) = 0 Then

            'Delete entire row
            Sheets("sheetname").Range("A" & row).EntireRow.Delete

        Else

            'Increse row
            row = row + 1

        End If

    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: I get Run-time error '13': Type mismatch. on the line `Do While Sheets("Publish").Range("A" & row) <> "`

Comment: I've got to downvote this answer.  By going forward with the loop rather than backward, this code will skip any back-to-back rows that should be deleted.  In the example, this code will miss (not delete) rows 5 and 10.

Comment: Yes, I modified my code for that error. Now, it work well. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Try this small macro.....it examines the sum of the section of each row:

```
Sub RowKiller()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long, wf As WorksheetFunction
    Dim rng As Range
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction

    For i = N To 2 Step -1
        Set rng = Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 4))
        If wf.Sum(rng) = 0 Then
            rng.EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Run-time error '1004': Unable to get the Sum property of the WorksheetFunction class

Answer (score 0):

Create a string of rows to delete then do ONE delete. No need to poll backwards when you do it this way and it should be a LOT faster than deleting row by row:

```
Sub DeleteRows()
Dim i As Long, DelRange As String
For i = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'Doesn't matter which way you go when you delete in one go
    If CLng(Cells(i, 1)) = 0 And CLng(Cells(i, 2)) = 0 And CLng(Cells(i, 3)) = 0 And CLng(Cells(i, 4)) = 0 Then DelRange = DelRange & "," & i & ":" & i
Next i
Range(Right(DelRange, Len(DelRange) - 1)).Delete
End Sub
```

Used CLng to convert the string zero to a Long zero for the test.

A small word of warning though, CLng(activecell) will return 0 if the activecell is blank so blank rows will be deleted also.

Edit: Put in a IsNumeric test to counter errors when strings are encountered (Can't CLng a true string)

```
Sub DeleteRows()
Dim i As Long, DelRange As String
For i = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'Doesn't matter which way you go when you delete in one go
    If IsNumeric(Cells(i, 1)) And IsNumeric(Cells(i, 2)) And IsNumeric(Cells(i, 3)) And IsNumeric(Cells(i, 4)) Then
        If CLng(Cells(i, 1)) = 0 And CLng(Cells(i, 2)) = 0 And CLng(Cells(i, 3)) = 0 And CLng(Cells(i, 4)) = 0 Then DelRange = DelRange & "," & i & ":" & i
    End If
Next i
Range(Right(DelRange, Len(DelRange) - 1)).Delete
End Sub
```